# Numerical solution of constant KappaTau curvature

Tags: differential-equations

EDIT2:

kaptau={kap1'[s]/kap1[s]+tau1'[s]/tau1[s]==0,kap1[s]==Cross[r'[s],r''[s]]/Norm[r'[s]]^3,
tau1[s]==ScalarTripleProduct[r'[s],r''[s],r'''[s]]/Norm[r'[s],r''[s]]^2,
kap1[0]==.5,tau1[0]==2.};

NDSolve[kaptau,{kap1,tau1},r,{s,0,3}]

Completely redone as above however still gives a single argument length error for $ \kappa$. What could be workaround for it?

---

In trying to numerically find a curve of constant [Curvature&Tosion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288907/a-space-curve-with-constant-curvature-torsion-product) product  the following  error (literal mismatch of $r$) occurs which please help resolve.

```
  cp[s_] = Cross[r'[s], r''[s]]; cpn[s_] = Norm[cp[s]];
torcurv = {ScalarTripleProduct[r'[s], r''[s], r'''[s]] cp[s]/cpn[s]^2/
     Norm[r'[s]]^3 == 1, r[0] == {.1, .15, .2}, r'[0] == {.8, .5, .1},
   r''[0] == {.08, .05, .02}}
NDSolve[torcurv, r, {s, 0, 3}]
```

EDIT1:

When first line is changed as

```
cp[r_[s_]] = Cross[r'[s], r''[s]]; cpn[cp[r_[s_]]] = Norm[cp_[r[s]]];
```

it becomes underdetermined treating $r,cp$ as independent functions

Comment: Your highest order derivative is 2, yet you only provide one initial condition?

Comment: Thanks, included derivative i.c.. Second order  i.c. needs also to be given as highest order is 3 , but code errors at first

Comment: You have one scalar equation for a 3 dimensional vector, what do you expect the answer to be?

Comment: please suggest a required change or an example in the documents.